# java.library.path has no effect in IntelliJ on linux

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, java.library.path

I'm encountering a strange issue with java.library.path on linux and I'm not sure if the problem is with IntelliJ idea or differences in the way java.library.path is used on windows and linux.

The setup is that in Intellij I create a simple JUnit4 test case which looks like this:

```
     System.out.println("java.library.path = " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
    System.out.println("LD_LIBRARY_PATH = " + System.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"));

    String directory = Paths.get("../../../../test-project/linux32").toAbsolutePath().toRealPath().toString();

    System.out.println("Loading: " + directory + "/dummy.so" + " with System.load(..)");
    System.load(directory + "/dummy.so");
    System.out.println("SUCCESS!");

    System.out.println("Loading: " + "dummy" + " with System.loadLibrary(..)");
    System.loadLibrary("dummy");
    System.out.println("SUCCESS!");
```

In order to set the java.library.path for the given test case I go to `Edit Configurations...` and set `-ea -Djava.library.path=</path/to/directory/containing/dummy.so>` in `VM options`, but after running the test case this is the output:

```
java.library.path = </path/to/directory/containing/dummy.so>
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = </path/to/directory/containing/dummy.so>
Loading: </path/to/directory/containing/dummy.so>/dummy.so with System.load(..)
SUCCESS!
Loading: dummy with System.loadLibrary(..)

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dummy in java.library.path

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at LoadLibraryTest.loadLibraryTest(LoadLibraryTest.java:21)
```

As you can see I try to load the library with `System.load(...)` first which works, and I've also tried to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` under `Environment variables` in `Edit Configurations...` to the same directory as `java.library.path` without any success. The issue is not related to dependent libraries not begin found because of the given `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dummy in java.library.path` error.

When I try this same setup in windows everything works and the library is successfully loaded as long as I've set the `java.library.path` correctly. If the `java.library.path` is incorrect the test also fails on windows obviously. I have tried both with and without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `java.library.path` and every combination of the two with no change in results on linux. It almost seems like setting the `java.library.path` has no effect on linux, but I don't know if this is a bug in IntelliJ or something related to linux.

**EDIT:**

In the original test case showed here the library was called `libdummy.so` and in that case simply removing the `lib` prefix in the call to `System.loadLibrary` worked, but in my real case scenario the library does not have a `lib` prefix, so I have now updated the test case accordingly and recompiled the test library with the name `dummy.so` and now the test case is failing with the same error again as explained above. Thanks to KC Wong for this tip!

Thanks in advance for any help on this matter!

-Martin

Comment: If your file is "libdummy.so", you should use "dummy" in System.loadLibrary(). This behavior is different from Windows. If libdummy.so has dependencies, make sure they can also be found via LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That actually worked in my simple test case here, but in the real scenario, the library I'm trying to load does not have the 'lib' prefix so I've made a change in my test case now to that the lib is called 'dummy.so' instead of 'libdummy.so' and then it no longer works again. Will update the original post, and thank you for your tip!

Comment: lib[Name].so is the naming convention for shared objects in Linux. I think it's best to rename the library you're trying to load.

Comment: That is an option I guess...

Comment: I stumbled into something and remembered this question. If you have an absolute path, you can use System.load(String absolutePath) instead of System.loadLibrary(String libraryName).

Comment: That's true. However, the nice thing about System.loabLibrary(String libraryName) is that you don't need any platform specific stuff in the 'libraryName'.